# Project On The Fly CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, qgis-2.18

i am going through the qgis 2.18 training manual, Forestry Application (georeferencing) I am using Windows OS8.
 When i load rautjarvi_aerial.tif or forest_stands.shp layers, there is no visual.

When i click on Zoom to layer, they will show but the other layers will now show.

I have followed the manual instructions to the letter but no luck. Is there a bug i am unaware of?

Any assistance will be nice.

Comment: did you check the projections match?

Comment: Yes i did, the layers does not change their CRS to the Project CRS. So i thought it might be a bug

Comment: can't you get to them if you choose "zoom to layer"?

Comment: Yes, rautjarvi_aerial.tif or forest_stands.shp layers will show but the other layers that i was working will not show until i zoom to their layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug. I just follow the procedure, with success:

[image]

GCP used:

```
mapX,mapY,pixelX,pixelY,enable
2557000,6786000,472.16666666666776564,-4353.05263157894751203,1
2559000,6787000,2840.13157894737014431,-3184.84210526315837342,1
2557000,6789000,488.48245614035238304,-810.62280701754411893,1
2559000,6789000,2850.46491228070226498,-824.4912280701751115,1
```

Comment: Great, but i can't get it on my system. Are you using 2.18 version on a windows system

Comment: @VaughnWilson I'm using 2.18.7 version in MacOS. But is not a bug, I think you don't set correct CRS in georeferencer plugin (EPSG: 2392). Check that and set GCP's again.

Comment: Yes, it worked. It was my GCP that was causing the trouble. Thanks Aldo